# peano axioms coherence

Tags: logic

Can anyone help me to solve this problem :

if every formula Φ that is provable in PA is such that N |= Φ then PA is consistent.

What is the basic idea in this problem?

Thank you

Miguel

Comment: Assume PA inconsistent. Then you can prove $1=2$ from it. But ver crtainly don't have $N\vDash 1=2$

Comment: The intuitive content of the above statement is that : if every theorem (this is the meaning of: "every formula $\varphi$ provable in $PA$") is true in $\mathbb N$ (this means $\mathbb N \vDash \varphi$), then $PA$ is consistent". Why ? Because in a model (and $\mathbb N$ is a model - the "standard" one - of $PA$) we cannot have, for a formula $\varphi$ whatever, $\varphi$ and $\lnot \varphi$ both *true*.

Comment: thank Mauro, so we can assume that N is the model (standard) for PA and, because  N ⊨ φ for every φ  , we cannot have -φ true in N. am i right?

Comment: Yes - see also Peter Smith's answer: we **assume** that $\mathbb N$ is **the** standard model, and models have the property that no sentence and its negation can be both true in them.

Comment: Perfect, we can assume N as model for PA , because all the PA's are valid in N, right?

Comment: Yes; but we "started with" our intuition of natural numbers: this is the domain $\mathbb N$. Then we (Peano and Dedekind) formalize "simple" axioms that are obviously *true* according to our intuition and our mathematical experience (we call the set of those axioms : $PA$). So, "by construction", $\mathbb$ is a model (the "intended" one) of $PA$.

Answer (score 1):

A theory is defined to be **semantically consistent** if and only if has a model -- i.e. there is a model according to which all its theorems are true. So the claim that every PA-theorem (wff provable in PA) is true-in-the-standard-model-$N$, implies PA has a model and hence, by definition it is semantically consistent.

And by the completeness of first-order logic, being **syntactically consistent** (proving no contradiction) is equivalent to being semantically consistent, so it follows from the given assumption that PA is syntactically consistent too.

So what's the problem?

Comment: thank you Peter . thank you for giving me and input